# Can't install Xdebug properly

Tags: php, xdebug

I tried to install Xdebug for my PHP project, but I supposed their was something wrong. And when I ran the script bellow I found on [document page of NetBeans](http://wiki.netbeans.org/HowToConfigureXDebug#Overview), I get the error:

```
Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.
```

Although, when I check with [Xdebug install guide](http://xdebug.org/find-binary.php), Xdebug is installed and working.

I used this script from NetBeans to check:

```
$address = '127.0.0.1';
$port = 9001;
$sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
$result = socket_bind($sock, $address, $port);
if (!$result) {
    echo(var_dump(socket_strerror(socket_last_error())));
    die('Unable to bind');
}
socket_listen($sock);
$client = socket_accept($sock);
echo "connection established: $client";
socket_close($client);
socket_close($sock);
```

And this is my `php.ini` where I configured Xdebug:

```
; Xdebug enabled...
zend_extension = C:\Server\PHP\5.3.8\ext\php_xdebug-2.1.3-5.3-vc9.dll
xdebug.profiler_enable = Off
xdebug.default_enable = On
; Xdebug remote...
xdebug.remote_enable = On
xdebug.remote_handler = dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode = req
xdebug.remote_port = 9001
xdebug.var_display_max_children = 128
xdebug.var_display_max_data = 512
xdebug.var_display_max_depth = 4
```

Any advice how to get things right would be very welcome!

Comment: I noticed you are skipping `xdebug.remote_host=localhost`, and I was recommended to add `xdebug.cli_color=1` int the php.ini. Plus, you can add  a log file and you may find more details there 'xdebug.remote_log=/some_folder/log/xdebug.log'

Answer (score 0):

Do you have anything else running on port 9001 such as a web server?  I would try changing the port back to what it was in the default configuration.